# Button group not wrapping when too long

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-4, buttongroup

I have a very long button group : https://jsfiddle.net/cyu4bvak/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label  class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" />ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    </label>
    <label  class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" />ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    </label>
    <label  class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" />ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    </label>
    ...
</div>
```

Whatever the size of the viewport it is always taking **one long line causing scrolling**.

Is it possible to **make it wrap** so that on smaller viewports it will wrap on more lines without causing scrolling?

If no which alternative(s) do I have to obtain the expected behavior?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the flex parent (`.btn-group`) if you want the flex children to wrap.

Comment: Simply brilliant! Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @Pragmateek fo sho!

Comment: when one button alone wraps onto the next line it doesn't look great, so I wanted to put the last three buttons in another div, so that a min of 3 buttons wrap. But when I do this, the last div always begins on a new line. Any solution to that?

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN

Answer (score 3):

For React-Bootstrap users:

```html
<ButtonGroup style={{ flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
...
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#wrap) you can add `flex-wrap` class to element with `btn-group`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the container is a great option, although sometimes I think it looks strange to have different sized buttons:

[image: stretched rows of buttons]

It's a little better if you also set `flex: 0 !important;` on each button, but the jagged block still isn't visually appealing to me:

[image: jagged rows of buttons]

Sometimes, I prefer a vertical column of buttons for screens below a certain width. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .btn-group {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

With a few more styles, you can also get nicely rounded corners:
[image: vertical stack of buttons]

Here is the full code:

```css
/* Responsive: Use a vertical column if under 450px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .btn-group {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -1px !important;
  }
  .btn-group .btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
  }
  .btn-group .btn:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h2>Responsive Button Group</h2>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Samsung</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Apple</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Xiaomi</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Huawei</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Oppo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Vivo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. In case it wasn't clear, both `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` work for both `btn-group` and `btn-group-toggle`.

Comment: Thanx for your example. I used the jagged Block but also put a border around it so that it looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `flex-wrap` to the button group will work in boot strap 5, but you should add `flex-grow-0` to each button so buttons will not grow to fill the container width